# Sorting a vector of objects containing two data members using std::sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, comparison

I'm trying to store data from a file into a vector of objects and then sorting the data members but I'm getting the errors "Cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "sort" is intended". I've tried using lambdas with sort and also thought it might be the way I've created my comparison function (is it a.hour > b.hour or should I use a.getHour() and b.getHour()?) I actually want to sort the vector by both hours and minutes but testing it on only hours first doesn't seem to work. This is what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class time {
    int hour;
    int minute;
public:
    time(int h, int m) {
        hour = h;
        minute = m;
    }
    int getHour() { return hour; }
    int getMinute() { return minute; }
};

class Times {
    vector<time> t;
public:
    Times(string fileName) {
        //
    }

    void parse(ifstream& file) {
        //
        sort.(t.begin(), t.end(), lowerThan);
        //sort.(t.begin(), t.end(), [] (time& a, time& b) { return a.hour < b.hour; })
    }

    void display() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
            cout << t[i].getHour() << ":" << t[i].getMinute() << endl;
        }
    }

    static bool lowerThan(time& a, time& b) { return a.getHour() < b.getHour(); }
};

int main() {
    Times times("File.txt");
    times.display();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First [you should not use `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).  Second it looks like you have a typo.  You have `sort.(...` not `sort(...`

Comment: Avoid `using namespace std`, Even more when you use name used in `std` as `time`.

Comment: Hi I've seen this in several places, but why to avoid using namespace std; ?

Comment: @FirstStep Check out the link in my comment

Comment: BTW, even without `using namespace std;`, it seems that your class `time` conflicts anyway with (C) function `time`, so use your own namespace, or rename your class `time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

You [**should not** use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to avoid name clashing.

Moreover, unfortunately your `time` (lowercase) class conflicts with another `time` standard identifier. Just use `Uppercase` convention for naming classes.

In addition, you may want to mark your `Time::getHour()` and `Time::getMinute()` methods as **`const`**, since they don't modify the internal state of `Time` objects.

You also have a **typo** with `sort` calls, since you have a dot following `sort`.

And, in C++11/14, I'd suggest you using **range-based `for` loops** instead of explicit `for` with integer indexes.

I've refactored your code a little bit considering those aspects, and [it now works](https://ideone.com/b6l6vS), with both the `lowerThan()` static method and the lambda. Feel free to study it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Time {
    int hour;
    int minute;
public:
    Time(int h, int m) : hour(h), minute(m) {
    }

    int getHour() const { return hour; }
    int getMinute() const { return minute; }
};

class Times {
    std::vector<Time> t;

    static bool lowerThan(const Time& a, const Time& b) { 
        return a.getHour() < b.getHour(); 
    }

public:
    Times() {
        // Test data
        t.push_back(Time{10, 10});
        t.push_back(Time{9, 20});
        t.push_back(Time{8, 30});

        //std::sort(t.begin(), t.end(), lowerThan);

        std::sort(t.begin(), t.end(), [] (const Time& a, const Time& b) { 
            return a.getHour() < b.getHour(); 
        });
    }

    void display() {
        for (const auto& x : t) {
            std::cout << x.getHour() << ":" << x.getMinute() << '\n';
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Times times;
    times.display();
}
```

---

Note also that if you define a custom `operator<` overload for sorting instances of the `Time` class, you can simply call `std::sort()` without any custom comparator, and your custom implementation of `operator<` [is automatically picked up by the compiler](https://ideone.com/8b1obR):

```
class Time {
...
    friend bool operator<(const Time& a, const Time& b) {
        return a.getHour() < b.getHour();
        // ... or a more complete comparison, including minutes.
    }   
};
```

---

**EDIT**

As suggested in a comment by @DieterLücking, you can use [`std::tie()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) for the `operator<` implementation ([live here on Ideone](https://ideone.com/Ps3xs8)):

```
#include <tuple>  // for std::tie

class Time {
    ...
public:

friend bool operator<(const Time& a, const Time& b) {
    return std::tie(a.hour, a.minute) < std::tie(b.hour, b.minute);
}   

};
```

Comment: For sorting: `std::tie(a.hour, a.minute) < std::tie(b.hour, b.minute);` or `std::make_tuple(a.getHour(), a.getMinute()) < std::make_tuple(b.getHour(), b.getMinute());` if the operator is no friend